# Visual Studio sizeof() difference IntelliSense vs. compile-time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(1)
class MyClass
{
  bool a;
  bool b;
  int c;
  char d[3];
  bool e[4];
};
#pragma pack()

int main()
{
  printf("sizeof(MyClass)=%d\n", sizeof(MyClass));
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
sizeof(MyClass)=13
```

But when I "hover" over `sizeof(MyClass)` I get:

[image]

This wouldn't have been a big issue but I'm trying to implement a compile-time assertion and it isn't working (getting a red underline):

[image]

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Which part of your question pertains to actual *compile* time? It seems like you have a problem with your UI/IDE only.

Comment: IIRC the compiler used for IntelliSense (which handles those mouse-overs and the underlining) isn't the same as the one use to actually build your program. Their behavior can be different, and in this case apparently is.

Comment: You may already be invested in your macro as well but I'd suggest that you use static_assert( condition ) since it's a portable way of doing the same IMO.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Right, the Intellisense compile logic is designed to work with ill-formed programs, the kind that result from half-completed edits.

Comment: Updated question compile time -> IntelliSense.

Comment: @rustyx: You updated the wrong thing.... the `sizeof()` operator is always evaluated at build time, never at runtime.

Comment: You just broke my answer, essentially by adding it to the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's true in C++, though probably not in MSVS...

Comment: @KerrekSB: The only exception I'm aware of is C99 VLAs, which MSVC  doesn't support (per C11 rules that make support optional).  Unless you're talking about completely unrelated topics such as .NET code -- but even then, `sizeof()` operator is compile-time, it just happens that there is *also* a `Marshal::Sizeof()` method that works at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a difference between compile-time and run-time; it is a difference between your compiler and your IDE's "intellisense", the latter of which appears not to support/recognise the `#pragma pack` directive.

**Ignore it. The size is 13.**

Since you can actually build your program, you know that the compile-time assertion succeeds, despite the "red line".

It is probably worth adding a comment before that assertion, explaining that users of Visual Studio 2015 will see a false negative in their IDE for the following assertion.

You may also wish to raise a bug on Microsoft Connect, if there is not one already.

Comment: Yeah I figured this was another bug in Visual studio... "Hope noone will notice" type of thing.

Comment: @rustyx Move the `#pragma pack()` to behind the `main` function and Intellisense will show the correct size. It looks like Intellisense does check the `#pragma pack()` directive - it just doesn't do it correctly.

Comment: @rustyx So, I just made another test with `pack(2)` and `sizeof(MyClass)` results in 14. It looks like Intellisense's evaluation of `sizeof` is always using the *pack size* it is currently in.

Comment: @rustyx And one other thing: `alignof` behaves the same.

Comment: Thanks. That helps in this simplistic scenario, but our code has much larger structures with a mix of different packs, so if I define pragma pack(1) before sizeof(), then IntelliSense gives a value which is too low.

Comment: @rustyx: Can't you ignore it? The assertions still work as expected. It's just the IDE's GUI being problematic.